# render a different component based on a condition within a loop

Tags: vue.js

I created a simple Minesweeper game and when it comes to the decision, which cell to render there are three possibilities:

- Unrevealed cell
- Revealed mine cell
- Revealed neutral cell

I created a row component that renders all the cells contained by the row.

```
<template>
  <div class="row">

    <component 
        v-for="(cell, columnIndex) in row" 
        :key="columnIndex"
    />

  </div>
</template>
```

I have to add the conditional statements now. From the docs there is a `is` tag so I tried to extend my code to

```
<component 
    v-for="(cell, columnIndex) in row" 
    :key="columnIndex" 
    :is="
        if(cell.revealed){
            if(cell.isMine) {
                <RevealedMineCell/>
            } else {
                <RevealedNeutralCell
                    :mineNeighbours="cell.mineNeighbours"
                />
            }
        } else {
            <UnrevealedCell
                :unrevealedCell="cell"
                :x="columnIndex"
                :y="rowIndex"
                @cellClicked="onCellClicked"
            />
        }
    "
/>
```

but I am mixing JavaScript code with HTML code and this is invalid. All I want to do is something like this pseudo code

```
<component 
    v-for="(cell, columnIndex) in row" 
    :key="columnIndex"
>
    <v-if="cell.revealed && cell.isMine">
        <RevealedMineCell/>
    </v-if>
    <v-else-if="cell.revealed && !cell.isMine">
        <RevealedNeutralCell
            :mineNeighbours="cell.mineNeighbours"
        />
    </v-else-if>
    <v-else>
        <UnrevealedCell
            :unrevealedCell="cell"
            :x="columnIndex"
            :y="rowIndex"
            @cellClicked="onCellClicked"
        />
    </v-else>
</component>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this inside methods.

```
<component 
    v-for="(cell, columnIndex) in row" 
    :key="columnIndex" 
    v-bind="getProps(cell)"
    :is="getCellComponent(cell)"
/>


import RevealedMineCell from ...
import RevealedNeutralCell from ...
import UnrevealedMineCell from ...

...
  methods: {
    getProps (cell) {
        if(cell.revealed){
           if(cell.isMine) {
               return {};
            } else {
               return {
                   mineNeighbours: cell.mineNeighbours
               };
            }
        } else {
            return {
                 unrevealedCell: cell,
                 ...
                 ...
                 cellClicked: this.onCellClicked
                 ...
                 ...
            };
        }
    },
    getCellComponent (cell) {
       if(cell.revealed){
           if(cell.isMine) {
               return RevealedMineCell;
            } else {
               return RevealedNeutralCell;
            }
        } else {
            return UnrevealedCell;
        }
  }
...
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But how can I pass in the props then =?

Comment: Oh, I forgot that part. You can bind dynamic props via method too. I've updated my answer. Check now.